# Filtering custom posts with Ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, select

I looked in other questions, searched on Google... And got nothing.

I need to filter the posts from a custom post type based on the selected value.

I have another part of the site where I use Ajax and everything works fine. I tried to follow the same logic, but everytime I change the select option, instead of loading the posts, I get a '0'.

There is no error on the console and I can't find where I'm getting it wrong.

**Here is my functions.php:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'load_filter' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'load_filter' );
function load_filter() {
$filterValue = esc_sql( $_POST );
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $filterValue['nonce'], 'ds_nonce_security_key' ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Ocorreu um erro. Por favor, tente novamente' );
}
if ( ! isset( $filterValue['opt_selected'] ) || empty( $filterValue['opt_selected'] ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Nenhum termo foi escolhido' );
}
if ( $filterValue['opt_selected'] == 'mais-recente'){
    $adsUser = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cadastro_anuncios',
        'author' => $curauthID,
        'orderBy' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
} else if ( $filterValue['opt_selected'] == 'mais-antigo'){
    $adsUser = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cadastro_anuncios',
        'author' => $curauthID,
        'orderBy' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
} else if ( $filterValue['opt_selected'] == 'mais-barato'){
    $adsUser = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cadastro_anuncios',
        'author' => $curauthID,
        'metaKey' => 'preco_anuncio',
        'orderBy' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
} else if ( $filterValue['opt_selected'] == 'mais-caro'){
    $adsUser = array(
        'post_type'  => 'cadastro_anuncios',
        'author' => $curauthID,
        'metaKey' => 'preco_anuncio',
        'orderBy' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
}else{}


$queryAdsUser = new WP_Query( $adsUser );
if ( $queryAdsUser->have_posts() ) : while ( $queryAdsUser->have_posts() ) : $queryAdsUser->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php echo the_title(); ?></p></a>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
else :
?>
<?php 
endif;

wp_die(); //stop function once you've echoed (returned) what you need.
```

**Here is my jQuery/Ajax bit:**

```
$("#opt_filter").change(function () {
    var opt_filter = $("#opt_filter").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: clocal.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'action': 'load_filter',
            'opt_selected': opt_filter,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#list-of-posts").append(response);
            //return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the page I'm trying to show the content:**

```
<select id="opt_filter" class="opt_filter" name="opt_filter">
                    <option name="mais-recente" value="mais-recente"> Mais recente </option>
                    <option name="mais-antigo" value="mais-antigo"> Mais antigo </option>
                    <option name="mais-barato" value="mais-barato"> Mais barato </option>
                    <option name="mais-caro" value="mais-caro"> Mais caro </option>
                </select>

                <div id="list-of-posts"></div>
```

Comment: in the JavaScript code, you call a action with "_" instead of "-" : `"action" : "load-filter",`

Comment: The function is load_filter. The action is load_filter. I can't see whats the problem with that oO

Comment: the function name is internal to PHP, the name to call in AJAX is defined by the action name `wp_ajax_load-filter` and there is `load-filter` here

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad. I changed that and it's working. Any tip so the posts won't keep stacking? Like, on each select, clear the last post list?
Also, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: to not stack, don't use `append` but `html(response)` http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Perfect! Thnx a lot =)

Comment: @mmm Can you post as an answer about the function name being internal and the action name? I think it's an important observation that might be useful for people with similar problems. And that way I can accept it and me this question solved =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @mmm, I just needed to change the 'append()' for 'html()'. And the use of '-' instead of '_' in the 'action' part.

I asked him to post it as an answer so I could close the question, but I guess he didn't see.

So, my final AJAX code is:

```
$("#opt_filter").change(function () {
var opt_filter = $("#opt_filter").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: clocal.ajaxurl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'action': 'load-filter',
        'opt_selected': opt_filter,
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#list-of-posts").html(response);
        //return false;
    }
   });
 });
```